# Why is window splitting forcing readonly?

Tags: vim

I'm using vim for programming. At the start of the day I'll open a file and proceed to do a couple window splits and open some files into buffers so they're readily available. Up until very recently this has just worked.

In the last week or so, though, something changed; one of my writable buffers is getting switched to readonly and I have no idea why. Here's the sequence of commands:

1. Open fileA.h
2. vsplit ./
3. open fileA.cpp
4. C-w C-w to switch to window containing fileA.h
5. sp ./

For steps 1-4 all windows are editable. When I execute step 5 the new file browsing window is readonly (as expected), but now the window holding fileA.cpp is marked as readonly too. fileA.h is still editable. Why is this happening?

To confuse me even more, if I don't do step 4 there are no problems (i.e. I split the window holding fileA.cpp instead of fileA.h). Also, if I do 'sp fileB.h' in step 5 instead of splitting to a file browser first there are no problems.

Comment: what are the plugins you are using? In general, try to eliminate interfering plugins. My guess, you are using something like NERDTree and it interferes with some other plugin's mappings

Comment: Does it still happen with `vim -u NONE`?  If not, @sehe is probably right.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It looks like this might be a bug in the netrw plugin. I tested with several versions of netrw with two builds of Vim 7.3 (MacPorts `vim` 7.3-353, and MacPorts `MacVim` “snapshot64” 7.3-390):

- v140 (included in the MacPorts `vim`: 7.3-353)
  Tested only with the MacPorts vim build.
- v141 (from the [`vim.org/scripts` netrw page](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075))
- v142 (from the `vim.org/scripts` netrw page)
- v143 (included in MacPorts `MacVim`: 7.3-390)
  Tested only with the MacPorts MacVim build.
- v144b (pre-release from the [netrw author’s Vim page](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW))

You can check your active netrw version with `:let g:loaded_netrwPlugin`.

v140 through v142 all had reasonable behavior when reproducing your scenario:

- Only the netrw buffer (from `sp .`; right side, upper window) is read-only.
  The `fileA.cpp` buffer in the window on the left remains non–read-only.

With v143 and v144b I was able to reproduce your behavior:

- Both the netrw buffer (right side, upper window) and the `fileA.cpp` buffer (left side) become read-only.
- Additionally (i.e. not reported by the OP, but seemingly related), the `fileA.cpp` window on the left side becomes the active window.
  Normally, the right side, upper window (the one from the `sp .`) should be active.

The `fileA.cpp` window was originally a netrw window (from `vsp .`). My guess is that something in v143 and v144b is a bit overzealous in resetting the old window for some reason (it probably should not be touching that window at all). `sp fileB.h` avoids the problem by not invoking netrw (i.e. the problem is not with splitting windows, but with something that netrw does when it creates the directory listing buffer).

---

If your problem is coming from netrw (i.e. your behavior matches my description, and your directory listing buffers have the text `Netrw Directory Listing` and (e.g.) `(netrw v143)` on the second line—assuming you have not disabled the netrw banner), then you may be able to fix it by installing an older(?) version of netrw (i.e. v142).

netrw is packaged as a “vimball archive”. The vimball plugin comes with Vim 7.0 and later. You just source a vimball file to install it to the first directory in your `runtimepath` (usually `~/.vim`).

```
:e /path/to/netrw.vba.gz
:so %
:q
```

If you are using [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) to isolate your Vim plugins (highly recommended!), you can install it to a bundle directory instead:

```
:e /path/to/netrw.vba.gz
:UseVimball ~/.vim/bundle/netrw
:q
```

Comment: This is some analysis effort, +1

Comment: Awesome response! It appears that I have v143 of netrw. Following your instructions I downgraded to 142 and it is working now.

FYI, I did see the behavior with fileA.cpp grabbing focus. I just forgot to record that detail.

Comment: Thank you Chris for your excellent answer. Diagnosis help and a detailed solution - very helpful.

Comment: rolling back to 142 via pathogen worked great for me.  147 is (currently) the latest version available and it was giving me even more serious problems.

Comment: I wonder if v150 fixes this.  I don't have a new enough version of vim to try it.

Comment: @PaulBrannan: I scrounged up an old copy of v144b and reproduced this problem on *vim* 7.4-258. Using that same installation of *vim*, I was unable to reproduce this problem with any of v147, v149, v150, or v153j (the current beta). So, yes it looks like v150 also fixes the problem.